# Comapring data from several spreadsheets via pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am working on simplifying a daily task and I wanted to pick up your brain. I have three different data sources (two from my company and the third from the costumer) with products, dates, category and volume. So far I have converted what I could and left out irrelevant data and combined two of the data into one pivot table (internal data) and the other one in a separate pivot table (external data download). My task is to compare the data and make sure that the internal data is exactly the same as external and if there is a difference investigate and change. 
I have been comparing the two pivot tables manually with a ruler. The data changes daily and sometimes it is a long task. From reading up on the forum I found ways to compare values with formulas but I have values as well as text and dates and don’t know how to incorporate it all. Any thoughts will be really appreciated?

Comment: If there isn't a huge data load I would combine all data into one big sheet (both internal and external). But, this is essential, I would add additional column where I would put either 'customer' or 'internal'. Than do what you did- simply use pivottable. After all you will have lots opportunities to make comparisons from  different point of views. For me that is the quickest solution. But not precise enough when using some formulas...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have some identifier to tell that this product and that are the same since you're using pivot table.

Something you can use will be `vlookup`.

The syntax is `=vlookup(lookup_value, range, column_index, false)`

Insert the number of columns for each item you will compare in a sheet where you have the internal data. If you're comparing dates, category and volume, this makes 6 columns you'll add and you can name them 'ext date`,`ext cat`and`ext vol`.

Sheet to make comparison (let's called it `Comparison`):

```
    A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H        I        J
 +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
1|Product |Int date|Int Cat |Int Vol |Ext date|Ext Cat |Ext Vol |Dif date|Dif Cat |Dif Vol |
 +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
2|Item1   |01/01/12|Cat1    |23      |vlookup1|vlookup2|        |        |        |        |
 |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
```

Sheet where the external data is found (let's called it `External`):

```
    A        B        C        D      
 +--------+--------+--------+--------+
1|Product |Ext date|Ext Cat |Ext Vol |
 +--------+--------+--------+--------+
2|Item1   |01/01/12|Cat1    |23      |
 |        |        |        |        |
```

In the cell `E2` of the sheet `Comparison`, you'll put:

```
=vlookup(A2, External!A:B, 2, false)
```

And the result will be `01/01/2012`

What the code does is looks for `Item1` in column A of `External` and returns the value in the **second** column (that's the purpose of the 2 in the formula) in the row it found `Item1`. You can specify any range (`A:B` in this formula) as long as the first column contains the value you're looking for, and the value you want to return in one of the columns included in the range. For instance, you could have written `=vlookup(A2, External!A:D, 2, false)` and it would return the same value since the index `2` is within that range, it won't work with `=vlookup(A2, External!A:D, 5, false)` since D is the 4th column, if that makes sense?

In the cell `F2` of the sheet `Comparison`, you'll put:

```
=vlookup(A2, External!A:C, 3, false)
```

And in cell `G2`

```
=vlookup(A2, External!A:D, 4, false)
```

`false` in the formula means exact match. You can also use `0` instead; it's the same thing.

Then you can put `=B2=E2` in the cell `H2` to get the comparison between the dates, or any other formula you are already using which might be more suitable.

I hope it helps! :)